# Cannot attach physical drive while creating virtual machine on windows 7

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-7-x64, cddvd

### Shared Drive Name is not accessible. You might not have permissions to use this resource.

Attaching the hostmachines drive (D:) to the virtual machine with 'settings' throws error:
Shared Drive Name is not accessible. You might not have permissions to use this resource."

Other vm's have a link to that drive and are working.
(running as admin on windows 7 x64)

Any idea's?

Comment: what virtual machine ? what exactl are you trying to do / are you using virtual box ? virtual PC ? windows 7 x64 is the host or hosted ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

Using windows 7 through remote desktop and then making a virtual machine doesn't allow you to pick the physical drive.
Go to your physical machine, pick the drive and go along with remote desktop....